# Orthonormal basis and unitary matrix...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u$ be a unitary matrix in $M_2(\mathbb R)$. 
Prove that if {$b_1,b_2$} is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^2$, then $u(b_2)$ is determined up to a negative sign by $u(b_1)$.

I don't understand what is being asked. Am I supposed to show that $u(b_1)$ and $u(b_2)$ are orthonormal?

Comment: Yes, you are. Hint: scalar product and transposition.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Is $u$ considered a scalar?

Comment: No, as you said, it's a matrix. Look at the definition of scalar product [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: What you call "unitary" is usually called "orthogonal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

Denote by $\;\langle\,,\,\rangle\;$ the usual inner product in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ :

$$\langle Ub_1\,,\,Ub_2\rangle=\langle b_1\,,\,U^*Ub_2\rangle=\langle b_1\,,\,b_2\rangle=0$$

Which means  $\;Ub_1\perp Ub_2\;$ ...

Comment: It's not a big deal but the inner product is not necessarily the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

You have $\langle b_i, b_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ since the given basis is orthonormal. From that how can you use the properties of a unitary matrix to get $\langle u(b_i), u(b_j)\rangle = \delta_{ij}$?